# Use browser to parse CSS without touching the DOM/styles

Tags: javascript, css

I have something like:

```
const someCSS = `
    .foo {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #ddf;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .bar {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .foo {
        padding-top: 30px; /* this overrides the previous one */
    }
`;
```

I can add this do the DOM and get back all selectors with each rule like this ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fbsdu5s/1/)):

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = someCSS;
document.head.append(style);

const styleSheet = Array.from(document.styleSheets).find(ss => ss.ownerNode == style);
const rules = Array.from(styleSheet.rules).map(rule => rule.cssText);

function styleToObject(rules, mergeWith = {}) {
    return [...rules].reduce(
        (obj, rule) => (obj[rule] = rules[rule], obj), mergeWith
    );
}

const styleObject = Array.from(styleSheet.rules).reduce(
    (obj, rule) => (obj[rule.selectorText] = styleToObject(rule.style, obj[rule.selectorText]), obj), {}
);

document.querySelector('pre').appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(styleObject, null, '\t'))
);
```

and get something like this:

```
{
    ".foo": {
        "padding-top": "30px",
        "padding-right": "20px",
        "padding-bottom": "20px",
        "padding-left": "20px",
        "background-color": "rgb(221, 221, 255)",
        "width": "100px"
    },
    ".bar": {
        "height": "100px"
    }
}
```

Is there another way to have the browser do this, without touching the DOM? I mean have a CSS text parsed by the browser (no regex) without actually styling anything in the page.

I though about adding it to a iFrame, but before its appended to the DOM the document is not available...

Comment: Isn't that what the lines before "document.head.append(style);" do? What is the goal here?

Comment: @TimGrant so I want to parse CSS text by the browser but without actually adding styles to the page that might paint stuff that is already there. I want to create a "cached" object or array from a CSS text. The `document.styleSheets` gives me what I want, but if its there then it already touched the DOM and is painting stuff... I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @Sergio, and I think that’s what your "style" constant is: an object containing CSS instructions. That’s why I’m asking what you’re trying to accomplish, because I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: @TimGrant so I want to go from that constant to a object where each key is the selector, and having the parse (or lets call it "separation of selectors") done by the browser that is best than any regex I might come up with. With that object I can handle css with more control like adding a "paren component" or element with a hash-ish class tag and avoid my styles poluting other stuff.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is no, you can't without changing the DOM.

If your concern is the added element triggering a redraw or the loaded style influencing the page in any way, you could add a "never-matching" media rule to the `<style>`-element you create.

For example:

```
style.setAttribute('media', '(max-width: 0)');
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/tgy4tdje/)

*EDIT*
Was working on an example utilising this trick/hack/solution, you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/8zg4s6qd/). Only now noticed the update to the question which is rather similar in mechanics (although my sample will work in less *green* browsers (not part of the question, I know)).

I've checked some sources which I've come across when I was trying to do a similar thing, most notably [MDN - CSSStylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStylesheet#Notes) is very thorough and states:

> A CSSStyleSheet object is created and inserted into the document's
>   styleSheets list automatically by the browser, when a style sheet is
>   loaded for a document. As the document.styleSheets list cannot be
>   modified directly, **there's no useful way to create a new CSSStyleSheet
>   object manually** (although [Constructable Stylesheet Objects](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/construct-stylesheets/) might get
>   added to the Web APIs at some point). To create a new stylesheet,
>   insert a  or  element into the document.

(Emphasis mine. CSO already mentioned by @Ouroborus)

I haven't done a lot of testing on various browsers, but I haven't seen redraws and/or reflows by adding the (media queried) style node to the `<head>`, unlike adding an `<iframe>`.

I'm curious if someone out here knows of a solution which relies on the (cross-)browser for processing CSS without hitting the DOM, as I haven't found it and ended up building a Tokenizer/Lexer to create such a tree).

Comment: Or `style.disabled = true;`. Though I noticed Chrome flips it back to `false` when you append it to the DOM, so with a different ordering (first append an empty `<style>`, then `style.disabled = true;` and finally `style.innerHTML = someCSS`), it should work and never affect the styles of the document.

Comment: In the future we may get [Constructable Stylesheet Objects](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/construct-stylesheets/).

Comment: Interesting, its a hack but quite interesting. Will test it out. (meanwhile updated the question, just to be more clear)

Comment: @Ouroborus is that like a proposal for a future spec, like in JS we have the `tc39`?

Comment: @Sergio Yeah, that appears to be what it is. Given how the process works, it'll be a few years before we see this, if at all.